# can't run background action in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have read carefully the apple dev user guide re multitasking but i still can't understand how i can run a simple operation while on background. I did the following simple experiment but nothing happened:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   sleep(3);
   UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"test" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil , nil];
   [alert1 show];
}
```

So I understand that adding support for audio/location/VoIP operations while in background in given by default, but how can I add support for such a simple operation?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Hope this ans. is very Useful for Your Problem

When you close Application than you can see in background the message in AlertView..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{


UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotif.fireDate =[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:15];
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    localNotif.alertBody = @"Staff meeting in 30 minutes";
    //localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'s Birthday",strName];

    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";
    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    //    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    localNotif.repeatInterval = NSYearCalendarUnit;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];


}
```

Comment: Thanks @jaydeep but my question was more general on how to handle background operations, not necessarily alert views. the alert view was just a visual way for me to know that the app is indeed working in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to show an alert when your application has entered background. Try printing some thing using NSLog or put a break point and check whether control comes to this method.

Comment: it does work when using NSLog,but I am trying to test it without the simulator...how can i accomplish that?

Comment: u can go to the home screen to test it on sim.

Comment: not sure i understand what you mean? i would like to test this while the device is not connected to Xcode, in "real life". what would be the best way to know that my app is indeed running in the background?

Answer (score 0):

your app can't do any UI stuff while in the background. you can do other stuff like fetch data or process some data while in the background.
to enable audio/location/voip you need to set you're info.plist properly to enable that.
should be documented in iOS docs

Comment: thanks but redirecting me back to the docs doesn't help...as i mentioned, i went through them already.